# Combobox Value Member to currency

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box that has product types and the associated prices that go with them.  I need to take the value member of the combo box which is the price and convert it to multiply it against another value and be able to put it in an invoice as currency.  Currently I can convert it to string but it seems I cannot just use a .ToString("C") overload to change it to currency.  Any help would be great:

```
    private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double invoiceTotal;
        double productTotal;
        double currentTotal;
        string multiplier;
        string price;

        //invoiceTotal = 0;
        price = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);

        multiplier = comboBox2.Text;
        productTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtProductTotal.Text);

        if (txtInvoiceTotal.Text != "")
        {
            invoiceTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtInvoiceTotal.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            invoiceTotal = 0;
        }            
        currentTotal = productTotal + invoiceTotal;
        txtInvoiceTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(currentTotal);
        string prod = comboBox1.Text;

        if (txtExplanation.Text == "") 
        {
            txtExplanation.Text = prod + " X " + multiplier + " @ " + price;
        }
        else
            txtExplanation.Text = txtExplanation.Text + "\r\n" + prod + " X " + multiplier + " @ " + price;           

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comboBox1.SelectedValue should already be a string. So you might want to then use String.Format to format it the way you want it. Otherwise, you could parse it into the double with Double.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue) and then call ToString("C") on the double value.

Comment: That worked thanks!  Used: string currencyText = String.Format("{0:C}", price);

Answer (score 0):

What you are likely looking for is a *string format*:

```
var price = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
var currencyText = price.ToString("$#,##0.00");
```

Comment: Still no luck.  It keeps giving me the same error:  No Overload for Method 'ToString' takes one argument.  Same one when I tried to use ToString("C");

Comment: What is the data type that you are storing in the combo box? Is it currency data?

Comment: Yes it is currency data.  It is the 'prices' of the products that we sell.

Comment: If the data was stored in the combo box as a raw Currency type, .ToString() should have worked. If, on the other hand, it was stored as strings, that would explain the failure.